# Is there a way to find out in Java the maximum allowed underlying read TCP socket buffer configured in the OS?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, nio

I know you can call `socket.setReceiveBufferSize(int)` and `socket.getReceiveBufferSize()`.

You can do something like:

```
socket.setReceiveBufferSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

int after = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();

if (after != Integer.MAX_VALUE) System.out.println("That did not work!");
```

Based on that, I would like to write an algo to guess correctly the max underlying read socket buffer size configured at the OS level. How can I do that? Binary search? Or is there a much simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

The `after` should be the maximum size assuming it didn't actually give you the size you wanted.  Making the buffer too big might actually hurt performance (as well as waste memory)

I would try to set it to the maximum you would want it to be, e.g. a few MB, and if that is too might it should be the maximum.